# Verificar dois campos nulos com Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho duas propriedades:

```
public int? Inicio {get; set;}
public int? Final {get; set;}
```

Ambas aceitam nulos e não são requeridas. Queria verificar se os dois são nulos usando `Data Annotation`. O funcionamento seria mais ou menos parecido com o [Compare do próprio Data Annotation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), porém verificando se o valor das duas propriedades são nulos.

Answer (score 6):

Quando envolve dois campos, o correto é decorar seu *Model* com [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) da seguinte forma:

```
public class MeuModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int? Inicio {get; set;}
    public int? Final {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        /* Verifique aqui as variáveis.
           Em caso de problemas, devolva erros usando:
           yield return new ValidationResult("Mensagem de erro.", new[] { "CampoEnvolvido1", "CampoEnvolvido2" });
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma nova notation para isso mandei abaixo como fazer você vai sobrescrever o método is valid

[image]